# How to get with paypal C# sdk, the transactionid of a directpayment method

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

Im using the c# sdk to do a direct payment to paypal.

Everything works great, however im not getting the transactionId because the sdk's "Payment" object does not have a transactionId nor does the http response.

the code is very simple.

```
Payment pymnt = new Payment();
        pymnt.intent = "sale";
        pymnt.payer = payr;
        pymnt.transactions = transactions;


Payment createdPayment = pymnt.Create(apiContext);
```

Pymnt Create method, creates and Executes the payment and retrieves back the properties by converting them from json.

I am getting back payid.I checked documentation but couldnt find any on how to get transactionId via payid.

Another part of my application that is created with paypal standard gets the paypal transaction id via the "txn_id" query parameter in the IPN method and saved it in the database.

Thus we need save the transactionid in the database to be consistent.

Please help.

Comment: take a look at this link and scroll down to the bottom of this page in the link to see the coded example [get transactionId via payid](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Q_28074646.html)

Answer (score 3):

(A similar question was asked on [GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/issues/70).)

The transaction ID for a payment can be found via the [`related_resources`](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/master/Source/SDK/Api/RelatedResources.cs) property of each [`transaction`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#transaction-object) associated with a payment.

For example, if you make a sale payment, the transaction ID can be retrieved via the following:

```
var payment = Payment.Get(apiContext, "PAY-89W644977H834061FKTDRCCY");
var transactionId = payment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.id;
```